# Android share intent. Whats App doesnt show up in the picker

Tags: android, android-intent

i want to enable the users of my app to share a text through whatsapp. I used the description on the whatsapp site:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

The problem, is that the system picker doesnt show whatsapp as an option, although its installed.

Is shareing with the share intent of android not possible anymore?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    try {

        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        waIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";

        PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        //Check if package exists or not. If not then code 
        //in catch block will be called
        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
   }
```

Comment: i get a message, that the app is not installed. but its not true, since whatsapp is installed for sure.

Comment: this method works for me. I suppose your whatsapp is not working correctly. Uninstall and install again...

Answer (score 3):

In line 5, replace by this, it should work now

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share text via.."));
```

The chooser allows the user to pick another application instead of default.